# Google Chrome extension synchronization, doesn't work for those I installed/wrote manually

Tags: google-chrome

I use google account to synchronize chrome settings, but when I moved to a new computer, only extensions that appears in the Chrome Store got installed, those I packed, and installed manually wasn't included, is there anyway to get those synchronized as well?

Comment: I think you will need to do it manually. Sync only supports apps from Chrome Store. You can sync the extension folder manually to some cloud service on both computers.